# Tor 4.0.2 How to change IP to desired country?

Tags: help, exit-relays

How can I change the IP to a USA IP address? I'm using Tor 4.0.2 on a MAC and have tried many different ways but all have failed. Please be detailed in the description as I'm not totally computer literate.